# Fixing DXF import encoding problem using PyQGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, encoding

I have text with French accent in a [DXF](https://sudbox.psud.nc/index.php/s/VMJj9BdS95jlEU0) I import in QGIS3.16. The DXF is encoded in UTF-8 but as a result, the features attributes have encoding problems. The `é` charcacter are written `Ã©`.
Here's a portion of the code used:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
layer = QgsVectorLayer(dxf_path + "|layername=entities|geometrytype=Point", "dxf_linestring", "ogr")
layer.setProviderEncoding(u'UTF-8')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

When I convert the DXF from UTF-8 to ANSI in Notepad++, the problem is solved but I would prefer to convert in the script rather than converting the whole file.

Comment: What about changing encoding in layer properties on the source tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I didn't find a working method because the DXF dataprovider has not the capability.

Instead, I used a file encoding convert trick:

```
with open(file_utf8, 'rb') as source_file:
  with open(file_latin1, 'w+b') as dest_file:
    contents = source_file.read()
    dest_file.write(contents.decode('utf-8').encode('latin1'))
```

And it worked perfectly for my plugin.